# Local variable in method being garbage collected before method exits? : Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, garbage-collection

I am using AWS S3 client to download big files from S3 (something around ~600MB). But in the midst of download, download fails with errors like `Socket closed` or `Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body` or `Data received in non-data state: 6`. Error message keeps changing from one failure to other. On little bit research, it seems that such issues comes, when `AmazonS3` client gets garbage collected before inputstream is completely read and written.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=438171#

Here is what code looks like

```
public void retrieve(String bucket, String key, String localFile){
    AmazonS3 s3Client = createNewS3Client();
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(bucket, key);

    InputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent();
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFile);

    //read bytes from inputstream and write to outputstream until EOF
    writeBytes(inputStream, outputStream); 

    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

So my question is  - can `s3Client` in above method be garbage collected if method `writeBytes` takes longer time to finish and before it can complete and return? There are no reference to `s3Client` in `writeBytes` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my answer here which actually solved the problem.

**What didn't work:**
To avoid garbage collection, I had added a log statement in the end which used `s3Client` object.

As suggested by people in comments, making `s3Client` a field in class was one option but I was not in a position to make that change. That might have fixed the issue though.

**What fixed the issue:**
Using API [getObject(GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest, File destinationFile)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest,%20java.io.File%29). It takes care of stream handling, reading the content from stream and writing to a file.